# Issue uploading to file sharing website PHP

Tags: php

Currently I have the following code.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);    
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$df = upload('username','password','song.mp3','song.mp3');
$df = json_decode($df, true);

function upload($login,$password,$filename,$file) { 
    $ch = curl_init();
    $postData = array(
        'op' => 'login',
        'login' => $login,
        'password' => $password,
        'returnto' => '/'
    );
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'http://dopefile.pk/login.html',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION => true,
        CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => 'cookie.txt'
    ));
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://dopefile.pk/?op=upload");
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $html = str_get_html($output);
    $ret1 = $html->find('form[id=uploadfile]'); 
    $ret = $html->find('form[id=uploadfile] input');
    foreach($ret AS $r) { 
        $newPost[$r->name]=$r->value;
    }
    $newPost['file_0'] = '@'.$file.';filename='.$filename;
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'http://dopefile.pk/cgi-bin/upload.cgi?upload_type=file',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $newPost,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION => true,
        CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => 'cookie.txt'
    ));
    return $output = curl_exec($ch);
}
```

Which is trying to upload to the file sharing website the file `song.mp3` which is within my directory, and then return the file sharing websites link (if you download the [simple_html_dom.php](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) files and try and run the code above, you can see that it returns no errors or returns no file sharing link + does not upload to my account on the website...

The cookies file updates with the cookies that show I successfully logged in, how ever I can't get the actual file link returned can anyone help me please?

Comment: I think that's because you're still using the old way of uploading files, You should be using ``curl_file_create`` instead or set CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD = false

Comment: @ahmad that is for certain not his issue lol

Comment: @ahmad I have tried messing around with both request you recommended but no luck so far, I can't figure out what the issue is to save my life.. I assume nobody else knows either..

Comment: The actual file upload is handled via xhr `http://dopefile.pk/js/upload.js` which generates upload_id, checks progress, and at success generates redirect url to page with link to uploaded file. Pretty complex stuff.